# Spring Cloud Function with Function Routing in AWS Lambda using API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, spring-cloud-function

I have tried to deploy a `Spring Cloud Function` with multiple functions in AWS Lambda.

For HTTP access I have created an `HTTP API Gateway (not a REST API)`. I wanted to use function routing as described here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_routing.

With the following configuration, the `RoutingFunction` shoud deleagte the call to the correct function based on the `function HTTP-Header`:

```
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers.function
```

The Lambda Handler class is:

```
org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler
```

and the configured function name (`FUNCTION_NAME`) is: `functionRouter`.

When I send a Request to the API-Gateway, the FunctionRouter gets a FluxJust object instead of a Message object, because the RequestHandler seems to be a Publisher.
So I get the following exception:

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on object of type
'reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust' - maybe not public or not valid?:
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
EL1008E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on object of type
'reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

My current workaround is to intercept the request before the request is delegated to the `RoutingFunction` and try to reconstruct the payload from the `HashMap` with the following code:

```
@Autowired
RoutingFunction f;

@Bean
public Function<Message<LinkedHashMap>,?> router() {
    return value -> {
        String json = new JSONObject(value.getPayload()).toString();
        Message<?> m = MessageBuilder.createMessage(json, value.getHeaders());
        Object result = f.apply(m);
        return result;
    };
}
```

Is there a way proper way to use the HTTP API Gateway in combination with `Function Routing` in `AWS`?

Answer (score 0):

On my project I've set `function.definition` and `function.routing-expression` like that:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=functionRouter
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['pathParameters']['proxy']
```

This will be using the `org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.RoutingFunction` that Spring Cloud Function provides and the expression would get the function name from the path.

If you still want to use the headers you could do:
`spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['headers']['function']`.
The HTTP headers are added in the Message headers in the `headers` property.
So first we get the Message headers and then the HTTP headers and then the header key.